# Choose the Workflow depending on a Lookup Field option

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, cewp

I have 3 different Workflows (A, B, C), and a Lookup Field with 3 different Options (A, B, C too). I want when I choose Option A, then the Workflow A begin to work when I send the form. Same with B and C.

Any Option? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a Main 2013 Designer workflow.
- Create a string variable and save the value of the Lookup field into it.
- Compare the value of the variable to define which option is chosen and depending on that condition, use the "Start a 2010 list workflow" to start the respective workflow.
- Make sure workflows A, B, C are 2010 workflows, otherwise, they cannot be started from a 2013 workflow.